# Setting up a 3rd party js script inside an iframe (disqus style)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, disqus

I am working on a small embeddabble HTML widget that would talk to my server and that others could put into their websites (on arbitrary domains).

I want to use the iframe and have a script running inside the iframe that talks to my server back and forth (to enforce proper scope separation).

My current understanding of the flow is as follows.

1. A snippet that clients embed on their website looks something like the following:

   ```
    <div id="my-app"></div>
    <script src="//my-app-domain.com/embed.js"></script>
   ```
2. `embed.js` would contain code that appends my iframe to the DOM (inside the div specified above).
3. The iframe HTML source is requested from my server again and that HTML source contains a js script which contains all the mechanics I want running in my widget.

Is that the correct flow or can it be simplified? Is this how disqus does this? Cannot seem to be able to verify that.